# Update Flot plot with 2 series in realtime

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, plot, flot

I'm working on displaying 2 time series of values using jquery and flot. I'm using them for a small period of time and for now I'm sticking to the examples. Basically I adapted several examples to extract from MySQL database the series using a PHP script that I include in the JQuery script. All works fine this far. I wish to be able to refresh this series every several seconds. This refresh doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why. Bellow is the jquery code used to generate the graph. I put now part one of the script.

```
    $(function(){ 

  //add data source to flot. 2 datasets with same structure: data in UNIX_TIMESTAMP format, value in DECIMAL format

    <?php include 'datasource.php'; ?>;

  //declare datasets

  var datasets = {
        "temperature": {
            label: "Temperature (C)",
            data:   <?php echo json_encode($dataset1); ?>
        },
        "humidity": {
            label: "Humidity (%)",
            data:   <?php echo json_encode($dataset2); ?>
        }
    };

    //set fixed colors for each series
    var i = 0;
    $.each(datasets, function(key, val) {
        val.color = i;
        ++i;
    });

    // insert checkboxes
    var choiceContainer = $("#choices");
    $.each(datasets, function(key, val) {
        choiceContainer.append('&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="' + key +
                               '" checked="checked" id="id' + key + '">' +
                               '<label for="id' + key + '">'
                                + val.label + '</label>');
    });
    choiceContainer.find("input").click(plotAccordingToChoices);
    //define plot options
    var options = {series: { shadowSize: 0 },
              yaxis: { min: <?php echo json_encode($mintemp) ?>, max: <?php echo json_encode($maxtemp) ?> },
              xaxis: { show: true, mode: "time", timeformat: "%h:%M %d.%m.%y", labelWidth: "10"}};
    //draw plot
    function plotAccordingToChoices() {
             var data = [];
             choiceContainer.find("input:checked").each(function () {
             var key = $(this).attr("name");
             if (key && datasets[key])
                data.push(datasets[key]);
        });
        if (data.length > 0)
           $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, options);
    }
    plotAccordingToChoices();
    //define plot refresh timeout
    setInterval(plotAccordingToChoices(), 3000);})
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `setInterval` should to be a string:

```
setInterval('plotAccordingToChoices()', 3000);
```

Or only the function name (not calling it):

```
setInterval(plotAccordingToChoices, 3000);
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval

---

To get updated data from the server-side (PHP), you also need to do remote calls (AJAX). You may use [jQuery getScript function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

Something like this:

```
function updatePlot() {
    $.getScript('update_plot.php');
}
setInterval(updatePlot, 3000);
```

Then, in your **update_plot.php** file, you can return JavaScript code mixed with PHP (just like you already did):

```
<?php // here some PHP code to get your data ?>
// and here some javascript code to use the data
plotAccordingToChoices(); // and finally update the plot
```

Comment: You are right. In my script I already used without () and the result is still the same. The problem could be in the way the PHP script is instanced in the JQuery, because is like there is no refresh in the calling the PHP script. But I'm not sure how to force the PHP script to refresh it's data.

Comment: I also tried putting all plot in a different PHP file and embedding in a DIV and then using the AJAX refresh of the DIV loading that file. This would give me a refresh of the whole DIV, including legend and grids and it doesn't look nice since the DIV starts blinking, gets white and then repaints itself. I want to make it work as it works in the example of flot where data is generated automatic from mathematical function, just that in my case data is taken from latest values in MySQL.